# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' when converting JSON to a Map<String, dynamic> in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

Flask JSON page, as shown: [image: JSON output of the page] Alternatively, here is the JSON file:

```
["{\"atl_change_percentage\": 4914281715.26934, \"image\": \"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/4934/large/0_Black-svg.png?1600757954\", \"market_cap_rank\": 987, \"max_supply\": null, \"id\": \"0chain\", \"atl\": 2.65e-09, \"price_change_24h\": -5.1138319612315e-05, \"current_price\": 0.128283, \"last_updated\": \"2022-06-23T16:10:11.148Z\", \"ath\": 5.16, \"low_24h\": 0.124866, \"market_cap_change_percentage_24h\": 0.1666, \"source\": \"\", \"atl_date\": \"2021-12-14T21:31:35.868Z\", \"symbol\": \"zcn\", \"ath_date\": \"2021-11-10T12:21:06.184Z\", \"market_cap_change_24h\": 10327.35, \"total_volume\": 14424.28, \"ath_change_percentage\": -97.47407, \"name\": \"0chain\", \"price_change_percentage_24h\": -0.03985, \"high_24h\": 0.133511, \"market_cap\": 6209045, \"circulating_supply\": 48400982.0, \"total_supply\": 400000000.0, \"fully_diluted_valuation\": null, \"roi\": null}"]
```

**Code in flutter:**

Class code:

```dart
class CryptoInfo {
  final int market_cap_rank;
  final double ath;
  final double market_cap;
  final double low_24h;
  final double high_24h;
  final double current_price;
  final int total_volume;
  final String symbol;
  final String last_updated;
  final String id;
  final String image;
  final double circulating_supply;

  CryptoInfo({
    required this.market_cap_rank,
    required this.ath,
    required this.market_cap,
    required this.low_24h,
    required this.high_24h,
    required this.current_price,
    required this.total_volume,
    required this.symbol,
    required this.last_updated,
    required this.id,
    required this.image,
    required this.circulating_supply,
  });

  factory CryptoInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CryptoInfo(
      market_cap_rank: json['market_cap_rank'] as int,
      ath: json['ath'] as double,
      market_cap: json['market_cap'] as double,
      low_24h: json['low_24h'] as double,
      high_24h: json['high_24h'] as double,
      current_price: json['current_price'] as double,
      total_volume: json['total_volume'] as int,
      symbol: json['symbol'] as String,
      last_updated: json['last_updated'] as String,
      id: json['id'] as String,
      image: json['image'] as String,
      circulating_supply: json['circulating_supply'] as double,
    );
  }
}
```

Code for building widget and getting data:

```dart
class _MainPagesState extends State<MainPages> {
  static late Future<CryptoInfo> Responses;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Responses = getData();
  }

  Future<CryptoInfo> getData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.24:5000/analyze'));
    final data = await jsonDecode(response.body);


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(data[0]);
      final Res = CryptoInfo.fromJson(data[0]);
      print(Res.id.toString());
      return Res;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load cryptos');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Settings"),
          centerTitle: true,
          toolbarHeight: 35,),
       body: FutureBuilder<CryptoInfo>(
        future: Responses,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data!.id);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Console output:

```
I/flutter (30283): 200
I/flutter (30283): {"atl_date": "2021-12-14T21:31:35.868Z", "price_change_24h": -5.1138319612315e-05, "circulating_supply": 48400982.0, "total_supply": 400000000.0, "fully_diluted_valuation": null, "current_price": 0.128283, "max_supply": null, "roi": null, "id": "0chain", "source": "", "market_cap_rank": 987, "market_cap_change_24h": 10327.35, "ath_change_percentage": -97.47407, "last_updated": "2022-06-23T16:10:11.148Z", "atl_change_percentage": 4914281715.26934, "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": 0.1666, "atl": 2.65e-09, "symbol": "zcn", "market_cap": 6209045, "ath": 5.16, "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/4934/large/0_Black-svg.png?1600757954", "total_volume": 14424.28, "name": "0chain", "high_24h": 0.133511, "low_24h": 0.124866, "ath_date": "2021-11-10T12:21:06.184Z", "price_change_percentage_24h": -0.03985}
E/flutter (30283): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
E/flutter (30283): #0      _MainPagesState.getData (package:crypto_app/main.dart:116:43)
E/flutter (30283): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30283):
```

As shown from the console, flutter gets correct the data and can get index 0 of the data (shown with `print(data[0]`). The problem is converting the data into a class CryptoInfo, and printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
Future<CryptoInfo> getData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.24:5000/analyze'));
    final data = await jsonDecode(response.body);


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(data[0]);
      final Res = CryptoInfo.fromJson(const JsonDecoder().convert(data[0]));
      print(Res.id.toString());
      return Res;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load cryptos');
    }
}
```

fromJson() takes a Map<String, dynamic> but all http requests return either a List or a String. In this case, you need to use the `const JsonDecoder().convert` function

Answer (score 0):

After sooooo much time, I finally found the solution to this problem.

Updated function:

```dart
Future<CryptoInfo> getData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.24:5000/analyze'));
    final data = await jsonDecode(response.body);


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(jsonDecode(data[0])['id']);
      final Res = CryptoInfo.fromJson(jsonDecode(data[0]));
      print(Res.market_cap_rank);
      return Res;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load cryptos');
    }
}
```

You need to use `jsonDecode()` again if you are using a list of JSONs. So, the line

```dart
final Res = CryptoInfo.fromJson(data[0]);
```

becomes:

```dart
final Res = CryptoInfo.fromJson(jsonDecode(data[0]));
```

Comment: Your 'JSON' is an array containing one string, which then contains JSON. If it was a list of JSON objects, which would be the sensible thing to expect, you wouldn't need to do this.